# How to use a procedure into the select and insert?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm work with store procedures, supose that I've the following procedure that return a value, and this value I use in other query.

```sql
CREATE PROCEUDRE filter(IN string varchar(1000), OUT salida varchar(1000))
BEGIN
  .....

END
```

And I want make a insert with a select query for example:

```sql
INSERT INTO  otherTable
SELECT  filter(concat_group(column)) , value1,value2 from mytable
GROUP BY  column,value,value2;
```

which is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you cannot call a stored procedure in the SQL select statement. What you want is like custom scalar functions.

reference
[mysql scalar function with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197552/mysql-scalar-function-with-for-loop)

Comment: What is the structure about this type of function?